# Can I use Pointer arithmetic on non‐array object?

Tags: c++, pointers, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

Following code is undefined behavior?

```
int main()
{
    int x[1] = { 0 };
    x + 1; // This is not undefined behavior.
    int y = 0;
    &y + 1; // Is this undefined behavior?
}
```

I want to use `<algorithm>` functions with non‐array object. e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{
    int x;
    // Is this undefined behavior?
    std::copy(&x, &x + 1, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout));
}
```

Comment: Which standard?

Comment: That could be a really bad idea. Since you don't actually know what's in `&x+1`, you could be overwriting all kinds of things there. Going over array bounds is a bad idea too.

Comment: @LightDrake He is not dereferencing the past-the-end pointer. Having one to represent a range is legal and a normal thing to do in C++.